# WYSIWYG Editor with image upload

Tags: html, editor, wysiwyg

I have been looking for a WYSIWYG editor to add into my own built CMS. I have come accross Nicedit, which is fantastic however, i cannot seem to upload an image and resize it.

Does anyone have any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to add this code on your page, without it you will not be able to do so

Also you have to change the configuration of the editor and make it upload to a specific location on your server or other remote servers

http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options